# Is that Sebulba in Ep. 2?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode II, as Anakin and Obi Wan are chasing the bounty hunter, we see a quick shot of a Dug who looks rather disgusted and makes a comment about Jedi as Anakin passes him.  Is this supposed to be Sebulba?  Or is it just another Dug?  I'd think that the reason they put in a shot of him was to imply that it was Sebulba, but that's just speculation on my part.

Comment: Are you saying that Dugs all look the same to you? Speciesist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is [Seboca](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Seboca).

He and [Bogg Tyrell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bogg_Tyrell) are in an airspeeder that is nearly hit by Obi-Wan.

He shows up again in Dex's Diner.

[image: Seboca]

<sup>(L: Seboca, R: Bogg Tyrell)</sup>

Comment: lol seboca sebulba.. not very far off from eachother. good job lucas xD

Comment: @MasterSkorh What do you expect from a guy who names characters Dooku, Fisto, Sy Snootles and Shmi?